# Difference between .equals and == in java (within memory)

Tags: java

Looking to gain a better understanding of `.equals` vs `==` in java

In particular I was curious how these behave at the memory level?

Everything I've read so far states that `==` looks to see if the objects refer to the same memory location while `.equals` will compare the content of the objects within a given memory location.

What is the advantage to comparing content versus the actual memory location? Is there any instances where `.equals` would behave different from `==` or vice a versa?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be very, very important differences. Two different objects created with the same values will *not* be equal by reference, but you still often want to see if they represent the same logical value. For example:

```
Point a = new Point(0, 0);
Point b = new Point(0, 0);
System.out.println(a == b);      // prints 'false'
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // prints 'true'
```